# Remove docker-py in setup.py before installing docker

Tags: python, docker, pip, setuptools, dockerpy

I have a package that depends on docker-py and I want to upgrade the dependency to docker.
Unfortunately those two packages don't play along with each other very well.

A safe way to do things would be to first uninstall docker-py and then install my package, which will install docker in its place (I already changed the requirements from docker-py to docker).

Is there a way for this to happen in setup.py when I upgrade my package (via pip or any other way) without messing up the python environment?

The first thing that came to my mind was to check, in setup.py, if docker-py is already installed and run `pip uninstall` like so:

```
   from setuptools import setup

   ...

   if 'docker-py' in [x.project_name for x in pip.get_installed_distributions()]:
       submodule.check_call("pip uninstall -y docker-py".split())

   setup(
      ...
   )
```

Setup will then install the new dependecy and everything will work fine.

Is this safe?
Any better alternatives?

Comment: I have never seen anybody do it, and I would **really hate if a package started uninstalling** packages when I install it. Why not instead raise an error and let the user decide?

Comment: I totally agree with you @NilsWerner, but the authors of docker-py probably never thought of the chaos they created when they changed the name in pypi but not the name of the actual module. I would expect an error when docker is installed while docker-py is still there, but I don't get that.

The specific package is installed and updated automatically in a lot of hosts and I would also like the situation be be resolved in an automatic way too

Comment: Aren't docker-py and docker the same thing, docker just being a newer version?

Comment: Yes but they have different names in pypi. It was initially created as docker-py but stopped at version 1.10.6 when it was renamed to docker. The module remained the same.

Comment: And what's the problem with showing an error and asking the user to upgrade to `docker`? If you are installing your package in some automated manner, just run `pip uninstall -y docker-py || true` before `pip install yourlib`

Comment: I will most likely end up doing something like that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip` is not a full blown package manager, it doesn't have such concepts as *"This package is incompatible with that"* or *"This package replaces that"*. What you're trying to do is emulating these important concepts. Unfortunately that doesn't work.

`pip` runs `setup.py` on user hosts only for source distributions (sdist). For eggs/wheels `pip` runs `setup.py` on the developer host and there is no way to configure a pre-install script to be run on user hosts, and wheels these days is the preferred distribution format.

You best bet is to ask user (via documentation) to uninstall `docker-py` manually.

Comment: I didn't know that wheel had a different way of doing things. Thanks for the tip @phd.

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple solution I did is - go to your folder where Python is installed, and in the 'Lib/site-pakages' delete the following files. Then reinstall the docker library again with >>> pip install docker

[For reference open this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAg03.png)

Comment: NO screenshots of text or code. Copy-paste the text into your answer instead.